# add quantity field for every product in the product grid view (ecwid ecommerce)

Tags: javascript

i keep on trying to manipulate my codes i put something that will define the variable but still not working and having a hard time with the error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Here's my code:

```js
Ecwid.OnPageLoad.add(function(page) {
  var x = "ecwid-BuyNow";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName("x")[0];
    var t = document.createTextNode("\n\n");
    container[i].appendChild(t);
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "number";
    input.placeholder = "Quantity";
    input.min = "1";
    input.name = "qtyAdd";
    container[i].appendChild(input);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please add line no. where this error is shown. More or less this error could because you may haven't added the class 'x' or due to placement of this script tag in your HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you placed your javascript code after HTML code, your loop is invalid. You iterate over length of string `x`, not over elements with class `ecwid-BuyNow`. And you don't event call variable x, but you search for elements with class `x`.

```
BuyNowEcwid.OnPageLoad.add(function(page) {
var x = "ecwid-BuyNow";
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(x);
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var container = elements[i];
    var t = document.createTextNode("\n\n");
    container.appendChild(t);
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "number";
    input.placeholder = "Quantity";
    input.min = "1";
    input.name = "qtyAdd";
    container.appendChild(input);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It runs correctly but it didn't show output result in the browser when i execute it through the console. it should have another field of quantity before adding to cart button.